# Remove a key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to python and I have the below query:

I have the below:

```
a = [{'1298': {'message': 'Please check the sensor of break for the truck 1298',
 'truckId': '1298', 'type': 'faulty sensor', 'timestamp': '2020-03-20 08:20:51'}}]
```

Is it possible to get:

```
a = [{'message': 'Please check the sensor of break for the truck 1298',
 'truckId': '1298', 'type': 'faulty sensor', 'timestamp': '2020-03-20 08:20:51'}]
```

I need the '1298' removed

Comment: Do you just want to remove keys for 1298 or remove all keys from list a?

Answer (score 1):

If you know you only have a single dictionary in list `a`, you could do:

```
a = [a[0]["1298"]]
```

Alternatively, if you could have multiple dictionaries in list `a`, this list comprehension will go through the dictionaries and keep the nested dictionary whose key is `"1298"`:

```
a = [d["1298"] for d in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

More generally, you can do

```
[value for b in a for key, value in b.items()]
```

to unpack all dictionaries in the list

Comment: Or just `[value for b in a for value in b.values()]`, since `key` isn't being used.